# Exception in thread “main” java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I'm trying to read data from a file and I'm getting the input mismatch exception above

Here is one line of data from the file

Willie, 11, 9

Here is a piece of the code reading a line from the file

```
fileScanner.useDelimiter(",") ;
String firstPetName = fileScanner.next() ;
int firstPetAge = fileScanner.nextInt() ;
fileScanner.useDelimiter("[,\\s]") ;
int firstPetWeight = fileScanner.nextInt() ;
fileScanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: when you use `fileScanner.nextInt()`, you are expecting an integer. If your input is not an integer, it will throw this exception.

Comment: Since you're splitting on `,` your first number will be `" 11"` and this is not a valid number.

Comment: The input is the data from the text file, I am reading the individual line that starts with "Willie"

Comment: Yes, I know and that do you try to read next?

Comment: Even when I take away the spaces in between the numbers, same error

Comment: Why not read the whole line, and split on `\\s+,\\s+` to remove spaces on both sides of any comma?

Comment: *"same error"* Either you did it incorrectly, or you're not seeing the same error. Instead you would see "no such line" exception message and this is a different issue in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with the sample you gave and this is what the problem is:

When you get the next element, it returns string with a space `" 11"`. You need to trim it first and then return it to Integer.

Here is the code I ran:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         Scanner s = new Scanner("Wille, 11, 9");
         s.useDelimiter(",");
         System.out.println(s.next());
         System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(s.next().trim()));//<-- Look Here
    }
```

What you need to change in your code is this:

```
int firstPetAge = Integer.valueOf(fileScanner.next().trim());
```

`fileScanner.next().trim()` will remove the space and only return `11`, once you have your number convert it to Integer using `Integer.valueOf(s.next().trim())`

Let me know if any issues.